# Should Maintenance Informations Such As "Service Will Be Unavailable At X And Should Be Back At Y" Be Publicly Available?

Tags: web-application, attack-surface

Suppose you are implementing a maintenance info banner that is publicly shown on your web application, meaning that even unauthenticated/unauthorised users can access this information easily.

Let's assume that this banner won't contain any pieces of information regarding technical implementations, versions of third party software, whatsoever, just plain information that it is going to be maintained at a specific point of time and order to do so it will not be available and maybe when it will be coming up again.

What are the security implications on this? Is this useful information for adversaries in order to time attacks on "sensitive" timings such as shutdown/startup of the web application? Are there any other considerations that should be made?

Comment: That the site is down is already public because it's down. So is the fact that it's up. Whether or not being down is a problem depends on what vulnerable state your service is in when it's down.

Comment: @schroeder Picture a website with a database backend. There's planned maintenance on the database, and when it occurs you can either notify the user of temporary limited functionality due to maintenance, or return misleading HTTP status codes and make it seem like the site is just broken. What might be better for keeping your site from being a target?

Comment: I understand the scenario you described in your question. But I don't understand what you want or what you are concerned about when you say that you don't want to be a target. There is no inherent desire to target sites that are down for maintenance. So, your risks are entirely contained in how the "maintenance state" exposes new vulnerabilities that are not normally there,